# Duplicate some rows in a sheet range using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a dictionary in my script of `key -> {list of values}`

I have a sheet which with these headers:

`key,  name`

I want to go over a range in a sheet and add rows of the values.

say:

`k1 -> val1, val2`

`k2 -> val3`

and:
[image]

I saw this [post](https://gist.github.com/develmaycare/4e72e72ae0be85a8efe7a525267afbc3)

The problem is that while iterating I change the range.
How can I do it efficiently?

```
    var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  // background color.
  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn - 1; i++){
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
      var kw_data = kw_to_label[rangeValues[j][i]];
```

Comment: aren't you sure there's not a problem in your graphic? how come in your example key1 has value3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- There is a range in your sheet with two columns per row, like `key | name`.
- You have an object in the script with different `keys` (where each `key` corresponds to a `key` in the previously mentioned range) and an array of values for each different `key`, like `"key1": ["value1", "value2", ...]`.
- You want to modify the original range so that, for each `value` in a key, a new row is written, like `key1 | name1 | value1`, `key1 | name1 | value2`, etc.

#### Solution:

You can do the following:

- Iterate through all keys in the object, using [for... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- For each key, iterate through all values in the corresponding array, using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) a new array element (with values `key, name, value`) to a 2D array (called `newValues` in the sample below).
- After iterating through each key, get a range with the dimensions of the 2D array `newValues`, and write the data from `newValues` to this range, using [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)).

#### Code sample:

```
function modifyRange() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const firstRow = 1; // Please change according to your preferences
  const firstCol = 1; // Please change according to your preferences
  const searchRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow,firstCol,sheet.getLastRow(),2);
  const object = {
    "key1": ["value1", "value2"],
    "key2": ["value3"],
    // ...
  }
  const values = searchRange.getValues();
  const newValues = [];
  for (const key in object) {
    const row = values.find(row => row[0] === key);
    if (row) {
      object[key].forEach(keyValue => {
        newValues.push([row[0], row[1], keyValue]);
      });
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(firstRow,firstCol,newValues.length,newValues[0].length)
       .setValues(newValues);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried something without having certain clarifications. I've considered your list of values were hardcoded inside your script. basically what you do is create a new result array and set the new values to a desired range.
**this is not tested** but the idea is more or less:

```
   const dictionnary = {
      'k1': ['val1', 'val2'],
      'k2': ['val3']
    }
    //range in the graphic where you have key and name so always 2 columns
    const values = searchRange.getValues()
    //future values to populate the spreadsheet with will be a 2D arrya at the end
    const newValues = []
    //loop through range where there is name and key
    for (let row = 0; row < values.length; row++)
      //check if key is inside the dictionnary
      if (values[row][0] in dictionnary){
        //get the list of values inside your dictionnary by key
        const tmpArr = dictionnary[values[row][0]]
        //loop through list
        for (let lign = 0; lign < tmpArr.length; lign++)
          //create the new row and push it to newValues
          newValues.push([values[row][0], values[row][1], tmpArr[lign]])
      }
    //generate the desired range of the size of newValues
    const newRange = sheet.getRange(desiredRowIndex, desiredColumnIndex, newValues.length, newValues[0].length);
    //set values inside range
    newRange.setValues(newValues)
```

#### Explanation:

- Iterate through all rows in the source range.
- For each row, check if the corresponding key is in the script object.
- For each element in the array of values for this key, push a new array element to a 2D array (`newValues`).
- Write `newValues` to the sheet via  [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)), where the dimensions of the range are based on the dimensions of the 2D array.

Comment: You needed to specify the number of column for `newRange` (that is, adding `newValues[0]`). Apart from this, this is a valid solution.

Comment: I had my solution ready when I saw yours, so I posted it anyway, as a possible alternative. It's very similar, but first iterating through the object keys, and using `for...in`, `find` and `forEach` instead of `for` and `if`.